# Comparing numbers using Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a script to compare two numbers:

```
#!/bin/bash

read X
read Y

if [[ $X -le $Y ]]; 
then 
    echo "X is less than Y"

elif [[ $X -ge $Y ]]; 
then
    echo "X is greater than Y"

else 
    echo "X is equal to Y"
fi
```

For some reason when the value of **X and Y are the same**, the **`else` condition is not executed**. Instead the **`if [[ $X -le $Y ]];` is executed**.

When I change the position of the `if` and `else` conditions:

```
#!/bin/bash

read X
read Y

if [[ $X -eq $Y ]]; 
then 
    echo "X is equal to Y"

elif [[ $X -ge $Y ]]; 
then
    echo "X is greater than Y"

else 
    echo "X is less than Y"
fi
```

The **`else` condition is executed** for this case. Can someone please give me an explanation to why the `else` condition is executed for one case but not the other?

Comment: (no need to post this simple fact as an answer I guess, hence this comment) `-le` means "less or equal", so I think you just want to use `-lt` and `-gt`

Comment: I would never use `[[ ... ]]` for such comparisons. Either `[ $"X" -le "$Y" ]` (POSIX-compatible) or `(( X < Y ))` (readable `bash` extension). The `[[ ... ]]` version is neither portable nor readable (well, less readable than it could be, anyway).

Comment: `[[ X -le Y ]]` works too, but I agree that `(( X <= Y ))` is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-le` and `-ge` are like `<=` and `>=`.

- `-le` = less than or equal
- `-ge` = greater than or equal
- `-lt` = less than
- `-gt` = greater than

It'll work if you switch to `-lt` and `-gt`:

```
if [[ $X -lt $Y ]]
then 
    echo "X is less than Y"

elif [[ $X -gt $Y ]]
then
    echo "X is greater than Y"

else 
    echo "X is equal to Y"
fi
```

You can also use `(( ))` for arithmetic operations. It has more natural syntax: you can use `<` and `>`, you don't need spaces around the operators, and `$` dollar signs are optional.

```
if ((X < Y))
then 
    echo "X is less than Y"

elif ((X > Y))
then
    echo "X is greater than Y"

else 
    echo "X is equal to Y"
fi
```